# How can I configure Firebase Authentication to work with mobile devices?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, mobile-devices

I am developing a web application that utilizes Firebase Authentication for user authentication. While the authentication functionality works smoothly on desktop browsers, I'm encountering difficulties when trying to authenticate users on mobile devices.

I have gone through the Firebase documentation and followed the necessary steps to set up Firebase Authentication, including configuring the necessary providers and ensuring the correct Redirect URLs and domain settings are in place. However, when attempting to authenticate users on mobile devices, the authentication process does not function as expected.

In addition to this issue, I have noticed that when users authenticate themselves on a mobile device, they are not displayed under the "Users" tab in the Firebase console. This makes it challenging for me to manage and track user accounts effectively.

I have also checked for any device or IP address restrictions that might be causing this issue, but have not found any. Is there anything specific I need to do or any additional configurations I should consider to enable seamless Firebase Authentication on mobile devices?

If anyone has experience with configuring Firebase Authentication for mobile devices or has encountered a similar issue, I would greatly appreciate your guidance and suggestions.

Please feel free to ask for any additional code snippets or error messages if needed to provide more context for the problem.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I checked my konfiguration, ans even set up a new firebase project

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should always provide the code that doesn't work the way you expect, and provide your debugging details.  Don't wait to be asked for it.  Please  read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example